# What is better: int.TryParse or try { int.Parse() } catch 

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, type-conversion, tryparse

I know.. I know... Performance is not the main concern here, but just for curiosity, what is better?

```
bool parsed = int.TryParse(string, out num);
if (parsed)
...
```

OR

```
try {
    int.Parse(string);
}
catch () {
    do something...
}
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

*Better* is highly subjective. For instance, I personally prefer `int.TryParse`, since I most often don't care *why* the parsing fails, if it fails. However, `int.Parse` can (according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx)) throw three different exceptions:

- the input is null
- the input is not in a valid format
- the input contains a number that produces an overflow

If you care about why it fails, then `int.Parse` is clearly the better choice.

As always, context is king.

Comment: While I agree with the general thrust that context is king, I'd say that TryParse is *almost always* better, it's a bit more than a highly subjective personal preference. Your counterexample (distinguishing the different exceptions that can be thrown) is fairly unusual, and would probably be better coded with a catch block for each exception type rather than the catch all.

Comment: @Joe: yes, if you want to distinguish between the different exception types, anything else than specific catch blocks would seem very odd. My answer aimed on discussing `Parse` vs `TryParse` rather than the specific code samples in the question. As I have mentioned elsewhere in comments, I agree that `TryParse` is *almost always* the better way to go, but the keyword is "almost", not "always".

Comment: @Joe: I already made that argument. See the comment exchange to the original question. Fredrik's right about absolute statements never being true. (OMG a paradox!)

Comment: Hail to the King, baby.

Answer (score 44):

Is it *exceptional* for the conversion to sometimes fail, or is it *expected and normal* that the conversion will sometimes fail?  If the former, use an *exception*. If the latter, *avoid exceptions*. Exceptions are called "exceptions" for a reason; you should only use them to handle *exceptional* circumstances.

Comment: I like this explanation because I parse a lot of user data, and whether failure is expected or not (and what to do when it happens) shapes the entire project.

Comment: Eric, I'd be interested to hear your thoughts on http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html: "``is this an exceptional (or unexpected) situation?'' This guideline has an attractive ring to it, but is usually a mistake... A more appropriate question to ask is: ``do we want stack unwinding here?''"

Comment: @Jon: Several things come to mind. First, that you can't argue with the tautology that exceptions are correct in those situations where you want the behaviour of an exception, but you can't learn anything from it either. Second, that "exceptional" and "unexpected" are two different things. And third, who says that stack unwinding has anything to do with it?  That's an implementation detail of C#. Exceptions thrown in async methods don't unwind the stack; the stack is long gone. They signal a task that an exceptional event occurred.  Don't confuse the semantics with the implementation.

Comment: I'd agree that the boost guideline raises the question, "when should we want stack unwinding?", but this quote also rings true: "The problem is that one person's 'exceptional' is another's 'expected'" Is a parse failure exceptional? Is hitting the end of a file exceptional? How do we objectively determine this?

Answer (score 25):

If it is indeed expected that the conversion will sometimes fail, I like to use `int.TryParse` and such neatly on one line with the [conditional (Ternary) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), like this:

```
int myInt = int.TryParse(myString, out myInt) ? myInt : 0;
```

In this case zero will be used as a default value if the TryParse method fails.

Also really useful for nullable types, which will overwrite any default value with `null` if the conversion fails.

Comment: This is exactly equivalent to: `int myInt; int.TryParse(myString, out myInt);`.  TryParse() already sets the result to 0 on failure.

Comment: Correct, but with my version you can specify an *alternative* default value, such as `10`.

Answer (score 11):

The first.  The second is considered *coding by exception*.

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I'd prefer:

```
if (int.TryParse(string, out num))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The first! You should not code by exception.

you could shorten it to

`if (int.TryParse(string, out num))`

Answer (score 4):

First, by far. As George said, second is coding by exception and has major performance impacts. And performance should be a concern, always.

Answer (score 3):

Catching an Exception has more overhead, so I'll go for TryParse.

```
if (int.TryParse(string, out num))
```

Plus, the [TryParse method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) does not throw an exception if the conversion fails. It eliminates the need to use exception handling to test for a FormatException in the event that the conversion is invalid and cannot be successfully parsed.

Answer (score 2):

Something else to keep in mind is that exceptions are logged (optionally) in the Visual Studio debug/output window. Even when the performance overhead of exceptions might be insignificant, writing a line of text for each exception when debugging can slow things right down. More noteworthy exceptions might be drowned amongst all the noise of failed integer parsing operations, too.