# How can I read user input from the console?

Tags: c#, .net, console

I want to get a number from the user, and then multiply that number with Pi. my attempt at this is below. But `a` contains gibberish. For example, if I insert `22`, then `a` contains `50`. What am I doing wrong? I don't get any compiler errors.

```
double a,b;
a = Console.Read();
b = a * Math.PI;
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Comment: Why couldn't you? Is it because of a compiler error, or does it not work as expected when you run it? Even though I can already see at least one thing wrong with it, on Stack Overflow you have to tell us exactly what you expected to happen and what actually happened instead when writing your question.

Comment: Read the error message -- it *won't compile* due to a type-mismatch in the assignment of the result of `Console.Read()` to `a`. Then, if still having problems, include the error message in the post.

Comment: @pst Considering that Console.Read() returns an int, no type mismatch!

Comment: One of the best skills you can learn is how to ask a good question.  In this case - what went wrong?  Was there an error message?  What was it?  What did you try to fix it?  What don't you understand specifically?

Comment: Closely related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24443827/465053).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I'm not sure what your problem is (since you haven't told us), but I'm guessing at

```
a = Console.Read();
```

This will only read one character from your Console.

You can change your program to this. To make it more robust, accept more than 1 char input, and validate that the input is actually a number:

```
double a, b;
Console.WriteLine("istenen sayıyı sonuna .00 koyarak yaz");
if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a)) {
  b = a * Math.PI;
  Console.WriteLine("Sonuç " + b); 
} else {
  //user gave an illegal input. Handle it here.
}
```

Answer (score 19):

```
a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Beware that if the user enters something that cannot be parsed to a double, an exception will be thrown.

Edit:

To expand on my answer, the reason it's not working for you is that you are getting an input from the user in string format, and trying to put it directly into a double. You can't do that. You have to extract the double value from the string first.

If you'd like to perform some sort of error checking, simply do this:

```
if ( double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a) ) {
  Console.Writeline("Sonuç "+ a * Math.PI;); 
}
else {
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid number entered. Please enter number in format: #.#");
}
```

Thanks to Öyvind and abatischev for helping me refine my answer.

Comment: What for try-catch if you can use `TryParse()`?

Comment: `TryParse()` is faster. See [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467613/parse-v-tryparse), [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945763/what-is-better-int-tryparse-or-try-int-parse-catch), [CH](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/tryparse-and-the-exception-tax.html),

Comment: I have to agree with @abatishchev here. I like the TryParse route much better. I don't think the user writing an illegal input to be an exception that should be catched. Basically I don't think exceptions should be a part of normal program flow.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I'll be changing my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 6):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
double d;
if (!Double.TryParse(input, out d))
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong input");
double r = d * Math.Pi;
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

---

The main reason of different input/output you're facing is that `Console.Read()` returns char code, not a number you typed! Learn how to use [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx).

Comment: Actually, `Console.Read()` returns an `int`. This is backed up by the MSDN link you have given ;)

Comment: @Øyvind: Right. But you can't use it other then `Convert.ToChar(x)` or `(char)x`, i.e. not directly. I updated my answer to clarify that.

Comment: But I'm not sure why it does not return char in the first place. Seems more logical to me at least.

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = Console.ReadLine(); //Reads a character from console
double a = double.Parse(str); //Converts str into the type double
double b = a * Math.PI; // Multiplies by PI
Console.WriteLine("{0}", b); // Writes the number to console
```

`Console.Read()` reads a string from console A SINGLE CHARACTER AT A TIME (but waits for an enter before going on. You normally use it in a `while` cycle). So if you write `25` + Enter, it will return the unicode value of `2` that is `50`. If you redo a second `Console.Read()` it will return immediately with `53` (the unicode value of `5`). A third and a fourth `Console.Read()` will return the end of line/carriage characters. A fifth will wait for new input.

`Console.ReadLine()` reads a `string` (so then you need to change the string to a `double`)

Comment: @abatishchev Because it should be `"Sonuç {0}"` (as it was in the first "version" of the question), but I was too much lazy to write it. I normally try to control the formatting of WriteLine instead of simply `WriteLine(myDouble)`

Answer (score 2):

I think there are some compiler errors.

- Writeline should be WriteLine (capital 'L')
- missing semicolon at the end of a line

  ```
      double a, b;
      Console.WriteLine("istenen sayıyı sonuna .00 koyarak yaz");
      a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      b = a * Math.PI; // Missing colon!
      Console.WriteLine("Sonuç " + b);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Sometime in the future .NET4.6

```
//for Double
double inputValues = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

//for Int
int inputValues = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        double a,b;
        Console.WriteLine("istenen sayıyı sonuna .00 koyarak yaz");
        try
        {
            a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            b = a * Math.PI;
            Console.WriteLine("Sonuç " + b); 
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("dönüştürme hatası");
            throw;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Console.Read()** takes a character and returns the ascii value of that character.So if you want to take the symbol that was entered by the user instead of its ascii value (ex:if input is 5 then symbol = 5, ascii value is 53), you have to parse it using **int.parse()** but it raises a compilation error because the return value of **Console.Read()** is already int type. So you can get the work done by using **Console.ReadLine()** instead of Console.Read() as follows.

```
int userInput = int.parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

here, the output of the **Console.ReadLine()** would be a string containing a number such as "53".By passing it to the **int.Parse()** we can convert it to int type.

Answer (score -2):

You're missing a semicolon: `double b = a * Math.PI;`