# Reading an integer from user input

Tags: c#, input

What I am looking for is how to read an integer that was given by the user from the command line (console project). I primarily know C++ and have started down the C# path. I know that Console.ReadLine(); only takes a char/string. So in short I am looking for the integer version of this.

Just to give you an idea of what I'm doing exactly:

```
Console.WriteLine("1. Add account.");
Console.WriteLine("Enter choice: ");
Console.ReadLine(); // Needs to take in int rather than string or char.
```

I have been looking for quite a while for this. I have found a lot on C but not C#. I did find however a thread, on another site, that suggested to convert from char to int. I'm sure there has to be a more direct way than converting.

Comment: I think you won't have *integer* version of `ReadLine`, you should hold the return value in `string` and try to convert it to `int` (may `Int32.TryParse` or other ans with `try / catch`), if entry not `int`, prompt user for another try.

Comment: Better way is take input in string variable and then use `int.TryParse` for conversion.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You can convert the string to integer using [Convert.ToInt32()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx) function

```
int intTemp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Amazing, I tried this before and it didn't work. But just tried it again and it did...Thanks
        Console.WriteLine("1. Add account.");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter choice: ");
        int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (choice == 1) // and so on.
This worked. Will mark as answer.

Comment: This answer is utterly wrong. Convert.ToInt32 or Int32.Parse will fail with an exception if the user input is not a number. Always use Int32.TryParse when you cannot guarantee that your input is a number.

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); and Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 77):

I would suggest you use `TryParse`:

```
Console.WriteLine("1. Add account.");
Console.WriteLine("Enter choice: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int number;
Int32.TryParse(input, out number);
```

This way, your application does not throw an exception, if you try to parse something like "1q" or "23e", because somebody made a faulty input.

`Int32.TryParse` returns a boolean value, so you can use it in an `if` statement, to see whether or not you need to branch of your code:

```
int number;
if(!Int32.TryParse(input, out number))
{
   //no, not able to parse, repeat, throw exception, use fallback value?
}
```

To your question: You will not find a solution to read an integer because `ReadLine()` reads the whole command line, threfor returns a string. What you can do is, try to convert this input into and int16/32/64 variable.

There are several methods for this:

- [Int.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx)
- [Convert.ToInt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Int.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you are in doubt about the input, which is to be converted, always go for the TryParse methods, no matter if you try to parse strings, int variable or what not.

**Update**
In C# 7.0 out variables can be declared directly where they are passed in as an argument, so the above code could be condensed into this:

```
if(Int32.TryParse(input, out int number))
{
   /* Yes input could be parsed and we can now use number in this code block 
      scope */
}
else 
{
   /* No, input could not be parsed to an integer */
}
```

A complete example would look like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        var foo = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(foo, out int number1)) {
            Console.WriteLine($"{number1} is a number");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{foo} is not a number");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"The value of the variable {nameof(number1)} is {number1}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here you can see, that the variable `number1` does get initialized even if the input is not a number and has the value 0 regardless, so it is valid even outside the declaring if block

Comment: Upvote. `int.TrypParse` is better solution. @Serv it will be good if you add if condition or bool variable for parse result. That should justify usage of int.TryParse.

Comment: Good answer, but entire thing could be simplified to single line: if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int input)){ //handle invalid input }

Answer (score 10):

You need to typecast the input. try using the following

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

It will throw exception if the value is non-numeric.

### Edit

I understand that the above is a quick one. I would like to improve my answer:

```
String input = Console.ReadLine();
int selectedOption;
if(int.TryParse(input, out selectedOption))
{
      switch(selectedOption) 
      {
           case 1:
                 //your code here.
                 break;
           case 2:
                //another one.
                break;
           //. and so on, default..
      }

} 
else
{
     //print error indicating non-numeric input is unsupported or something more meaningful.
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
int op = 0;
string in = string.Empty;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter choice");
    in = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!int.TryParse(in, out op));
```

Comment: This answer should be more up in the list. It's the only one which handles wrong input and lets the user retry without any exception thrown. I would only remove the `string.Empty` assignation.

Answer (score 5):

Use this simple line:

```
int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 4):

I didn't see a good and complete answer to your question, so I will show a more complete example.  There are some methods posted showing how to get integer input from the user, but whenever you do this you usually also need to

1. validate the input
2. display an error message if invalid input
   is given, and
3. loop through until a valid input is given.

This example shows how to get an integer value from the user that is equal to or greater than 1. If invalid input is given, it will catch the error, display an error message, and request the user to try again for a correct input.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int intUserInput = 0;
    bool validUserInput = false;

    while (validUserInput == false)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter an integer value greater than or equal to 1: ");
            intUserInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //try to parse the user input to an int variable
        }
        catch (Exception e) //catch exception for invalid input, such as a letter
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        if (intUserInput >= 1) { validUserInput = true; }
        else { Console.WriteLine(intUserInput + " is not a valid input, please enter an integer greater than 0."); }

    } //end while

    Console.WriteLine("You entered " + intUserInput);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit ");
    Console.ReadKey();
} //end main
```

In your question it looks like you wanted to use this for menu options.  So if you wanted to get int input for choosing a menu option you could change the if statement to

```
if ( (intUserInput >= 1) && (intUserInput <= 4) )
```

This would work if you needed the user to pick an option of 1, 2, 3, or 4.

Comment: Throwing an exception around user input without at least testing a value with `TryParse` is an expensive way to conduct user input validation

Answer (score 3):

I used `int intTemp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` and it worked well, here's my example:

```
        int balance = 10000;
        int retrieve = 0;
        Console.Write("Hello, write the amount you want to retrieve: ");
        retrieve = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 2):

Better way is to use TryParse:

```
Int32 _userInput;
if(Int32.TryParse (Console.Readline(), out _userInput) {// do the stuff on userInput}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will not throw exception and user can try again:

```
        Console.WriteLine("1. Add account.");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter choice: ");
        int choice = 0;
        while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong input! Enter choice number again:");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but with some newer C# features like lambda expressions, here's what I actually implemented for my project today:

```
private static async Task Main()
{
    // -- More of my code here
    Console.WriteLine("1. Add account.");
    Console.WriteLine("2. View accounts.");

    int choice = ReadInt("Please enter your choice: ");
    // -- Code that uses the choice variable
}

// I have this as a public function in a utility class,
// but you could use it directly in Program.cs
private static int ReadInt(string prompt)
{
    string text;
    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
        text = Console.ReadLine();
    } while (!text.Where(c => char.IsNumber(c)).Any());

    return int.Parse(new string(text.Where(c => char.IsNumber(c)).ToArray()));
}
```

The difference here is that if you accidentally type a number and any other text along with that number, only the number is parsed.

Comment: `text == null` will never happen

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number from 1 to 10");
        int counter = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        //Here is your variable
        Console.WriteLine("The numbers start from");
        do
        {
            counter++;
            Console.Write(counter + ", ");

        } while (counter < 100);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own ReadInt function, that only allows numbers
(this function is probably not the best way to go about this, but does the job)

```
public static int ReadInt()
    {
        string allowedChars = "0123456789";

        ConsoleKeyInfo read = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
        List<char> outInt = new List<char>();

        while(!(read.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter && outInt.Count > 0))
        {
            read = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (allowedChars.Contains(read.KeyChar.ToString()))
            {
                outInt.Add(read.KeyChar);
                Console.Write(read.KeyChar.ToString());
            }
            if(read.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                if(outInt.Count > 0)
                {
                    outInt.RemoveAt(outInt.Count - 1);
                    Console.CursorLeft--;
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    Console.CursorLeft--;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop + 1);
        return int.Parse(new string(outInt.ToArray()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable that will contain the value of the user input :
Ex :

```
int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just go ahead and try :

```
    Console.WriteLine("1. Add account.");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter choice: ");
    int choice=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

That should work for the case statement.

It works with the switch statement and doesn't throw an exception.