# VB FOR. NEXT. LOOP - square root of a number

Tags: visual-studio

How can I correctly use the `For Next` loop in my program. Is it a must to have a counter for the `For Next` loop. For instance `num = 1 to 1000` or can I have the user enter any number with the counter.

```
Module Module1

   Sub Main()
    Dim sq As Integer


    For num As Integer = num >= 



        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number")
        num = Console.Read()

        sq = num * num



        Console.WriteLine("the square root is " & sq)

    Next

End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: @Issac. How can i get the user to enter a number and find its sq in For next loop.

Comment: so what's the real problem? If you want to read an integer why don't search for [Reading an integer from user input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24443827/995714)? If you're **squaring** the number why asking for **square root** of the number? And why do you ask the user to enter 1000 times?

Comment: you should learn vb 6.0 before you use it

Answer (score 0):

here's how to make a Sqrt function and successfully using it no need to use a for loop to do what you want to do

```
Function Sqrt(x)As Integer
    Dim root As Integer
    root = x
    root = root ^ (1 / 2)    
    Sqrt = root    
End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Num = InputBox("Please enter a number")    
    Print "The square root of " & Num & " is " & Sqrt(Num)
End Sub
```