# How do i get my Console.ReadLine to only let user input numbers?

Tags: c#

I'm making a basic Math game. I want the user/player to only be able to input numbers as the answer. I could just write a different code for letters but I would prefer if they couldn't use letters at all.

Not sure if I use `Console.ReadLine();` or another function but I am only learning c# so bear with me.

Comment: I suggest you go this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29526801/2321042 If you need that in several places, you could put that inside a method just like Eric suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't. You use `TryParse` on the result, and if it is not an integer, you print "that's not an integer", loop back around, and try again.

Try writing a *method* that takes as its input a prompt string, a try-again string, and returns an integer:

```
static int PromptForInteger(string prompt, string tryAgain) 
{ ... }
```

You fill in the rest. Now you have a method you can use any time you want to prompt for an integer.