# Simple C# Calculator with Properties

Tags: c#, math, properties, calculator, derived-class

I understand that this Calculator can be written a lot more simpler than what I have written it but I want to understand the reason it's not working with Properties the way I've written it. I read in a book that I could omit the "set" accessor but I got more errors when I did. I'm getting the Main method error as well. Any help would be appreciated. 
Line 1(CS5001), 9(CS5113), and 26(CS0161).

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)

    { 

    public int number01;
    public int number02;
    public int Number03

    {
        get

        {
            return number02 / number01;
        }
    }

    class Program1 : Program
    {

        public int DivideFinal()
        {

            Console.Write("Enter a number to be divided: ");
            Console.ReadKey();
            number01 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter another number to be divided");
            number02 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
            Console.WriteLine("The result is: " + Number03);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

}

```
}
```

}

Comment: From what I can see, your `Number03` property needs another closing bracket after the `get` accessor.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that.

Comment: Look at `double`, integer division isn't particularly helpful. What would be printed if you did 10/3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have left out two closing braces and claimed a function returns an `int` which actually returns nothing.
It helps to either fix one thing at a time - and in fact try to write only  little code at a time, compiling as you go. If you can't see what's wrong comment out large chunks and try to keep your code neatly lined up so you can see where you may have missed a brace or similar.

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }//<-----------

        public int number01;
        public int number02;
        public int Number03
        {
            get
            {
                return number02 / number01;
            }
        }//<----------

        class Program1 : Program
        {

            public void DivideFinal()//<---- void not int
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a number to be divided: ");
                Console.ReadKey();
                number01 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter another number to be divided");
                number02 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
                Console.WriteLine("The result is: " + Number03);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

---

Right - now we have it compiling let's look at the essence of what you have.

```
namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

You have a class called `Program` in a namespace with the expected `static void Main` entry point. It doesn't do anything, so when you run it nothing much will happen. If you run it in a debugger, you might get "Press any key to continue" printed.

If you want something to happen, it needs code in your entry point- this `Main` function by default.

You have added some properties to this class, which you don't use. You have started to write another class, called `Program1` *inside* this class, which also inherits from this class.

Consider calling it `Calculator` instead, since that's what you are going to write. It doesn't need to inherit from your main class - they are unrelated. It is much neater to just make a new class in a new file.

Start a *new* class, and add the properties and other methods like `DivideFinal` in there. (By the way why have you called it `DivideFinal`?)

```
namespace Calculator
{
    class Calculator
    {
        public int number01;
        public int number02;
        public int Number03
        {
            get
            {
                return number02 / number01;
            }
        }

        public void DivideFinal()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a number to be divided: ");
            Console.ReadKey();
            number01 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter another number to be divided");
            number02 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
            Console.WriteLine("The result is: " + Number03);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, let's make the main function do something:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var calculator = new Calculator();
        calculator.DivideFinal();
    }
```

This will lead to some errors, which we can deal with in another question.
For example, `Convert.ToInt32` expects a `String` but you are giving it the result of `Console.ReadKey` which isn't a string. You may wish to consider `Console.ReadLine()` instead: see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443827/reading-an-integer-from-user-input) for example.

Comment: Thank you @doctorlove. I made the corrections but I am still getting the compiler error of CS5001 (No valid Main method for entry point).

Comment: If you save this file as Program.cs it should work. Or you change the Application properties (right click on project and go to properties) and choose the startup object. What is your cs file saved as? What is the start up object?

Comment: @Equalsk - once we have it compiling I may come back and comment further on the structure.

Comment: @docotorlove it's currently compiling but when the console opens nothing happens. It only reads "Press any key to continue." Also, the program is saved as Program.cs

Comment: There we go - some more details about how to make `Main` actually do something.

Comment: The method is referred to as DivideFinal for no particular reason. It is just the name I chose.

Comment: the code you provided did not work but I had errors other than what you projected. I had errors stating that no object reference was present in the main method which was my reasoning behind trying to create a derived class.

Comment: Open another question with that exact error message?