# C# Winforms Math Issue

Tags: c#

I have a little math issue I have stumbling around on. Hoping someone can help with it.

`label3.text` needs to be `textbox1.text * 100` and that product needs to be divided by the quotient of `(1000000/textbox7.text)`

```
`label3.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * 100 / (1000000 / (textBox7.Text).ToString("N3"));`
```

Comment: Dont forget to make your "100" "100.0d" to prevent the compiler rounding the value. The same applies to the million integer value.

Comment: Good advice-thank you

Comment: "C# winforms math issue" isn't really a helpful title. Please read [ask] and modify it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading an integer from user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443827/reading-an-integer-from-user-input)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't divide by `textBox7.Text` (which is `string`) but by `double`:

```
label3.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) * 100 / 
              (1000000 / Convert.ToDouble(textBox7.Text))).ToString("N3");
```

Please, notice that `.ToString("N3")` should be the *very last* method (= the value we've obtain represent in `N3` format)