# c# How to know what is user input choice?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm really new to c#, just knowing the basics..
I can't seems to find any solution to my problem I've tried every possible google search query.

So here's what I'm trying to do:
I want to determined if 1 or 2 was pressed by the user.

```
 int action;
 Console.WriteLine("ACTIONS: Press 1 to do quest, Press 2 to access teleport");
```

I'm trying if else statement but I always getting

> use of unsigned local variabled 'action'

Comment: I think you might find your answer from an earlier question: [Reading an integer from user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443827/reading-an-integer-from-user-input)

Comment: This surely can't be your entire code? Where's the if-else-Statement?

Comment: You should start with some C# book. No on SO.

Comment: The reason you're getting "use of unassigned local variable" is because you never set the value of `action`.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100285/how-to-detect-the-currently-pressed-key

Comment: Like i said i have tried if else statement, but i just get an error 'use of unssinged local variabled 'action'.

Comment: if you know console.write, you should know console.read too. Check console.read and make GOOD research

Comment: You didnt put anything in action thats why @JuanDelaCruz .. seriously read a c# book, this will be covered in the early chapters

Comment: your question need to be improved it's not well declared

Comment: @BugFinder I don't see why i need to assigned a value to action, there will be 2 possible action..in c++ you just have to check if the variable is equal to 1 and then it will do the condition.

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz this is a closed question now, and you are missing the point, action is empty because you never did something with it.. it cant contain user input - please read some c# learning books

Comment: @BugFinder Maybe you need to read my question again.

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz I can assure you I do not. You didnt use it.

Comment: @BugFinder Tell me how assigning a value to 'action' will help. You should widen your phrase "didn't use it'.

Comment: let me repeat this loudly "THIS QUESTION IS CLOSED - DROP IT!"

Comment: @BugFinder just as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the number by reading it. Like:

```
string stg = Console.ReadLine();
int i = Int.Parse(stg);
if(i == 1){
//some code
}
else{
//some other code
}
```

And the "error" you're getting is no error at all. The program is just saying that you've declared the integer type Action and has not used it.