# how to convert type string to int

Tags: c#

I have created some classes and in one instance, I want the programme to read the answer (numeric). I have tried to set the class as string and as int but continue to have problems. Please bear with me I am just starting to learn programming.

```
public **int** Age { get; set; }
Animal cuddle = new Animal();
            cuddle.Color = "";
            cuddle.Age = 0;
            cuddle.Name = "";
            cuddle.Type = "";
Console.WriteLine("Hi, {0} How old do you want your {1,2} to be?\n Remember, if your {3} is older then 5 you will have to give her double!!!", name, cuddle.Color, player);
            cuddle.Age = **Console.ReadLine**();
            if (cuddle.Age < 5)
            {
```

In this instance it doesn't accept the `Console.ReadLine.` 
If I change the int to string as:

```
 public **string** Age { get; set; }
```

then it doesn't accept

```
if (**cuddle.Age < 5**)
```

I have tried without the brackets and/or with `(**cuddle.Age = < 5**)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int age = 0;
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age)) //It can be parsed as integer:
{
     if(age < 5)
     {
        // do your work
     }
}
```

You can go further more and repeat reading line while the input is not parse-able:

```
int age = 0;
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age));
if(age < 5)
{
   // do your work
}
```

Here is the **[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2kUCyo)**

Comment: Thanks Ashkan. It didn't show any errors but it didn't work at the end. It shut me out when this question was answered. Can you help me?

Comment: @Itzik please come to discuss in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153406/discussion-between-rev4-and-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani)

Answer (score 1):

You can cast to an int, on user input:

```
int theInt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

This is possibly a duplicate of this question:  [Reading an integer from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443827/reading-an-integer-from-user-input)