# main.cs(35,34): error CS1041: Identifier expected, `in' is a keyword

Tags: c#

I don't know C# but I have homework to convert from Java to C# or C and I have found an online converter, but when I put the code to C# compiler, I get this error

> main.cs(35,34): error CS1041: Identifier expected, `in' is a keyword

This is my C# code:

```
using System;

public class JavaApplication
{
    public static void selectionSort(int[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            int index = i;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j] < arr[index])
                {
                    index = j; //searching for lowest index
                }
            }

            int smallerNumber = arr[index];

            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = smallerNumber;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        int[] arr1 = new int[10];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Console.WriteLine("Before Selection Sort:");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            arr1[i] = scan.Next();
        }

        selectionSort(arr1);

        Console.WriteLine("After Selection Sort");

        foreach (int i in arr1)
        {
           Console.Write(i + " ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");
        int sumEven = 0;
        int sumOdd = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
           if (arr1[j] % 2 == 0)
           {
               sumEven++;
           }
           else
           {
               sumOdd++;
           }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The number of even numbers in this array is:" + sumEven);
        Console.WriteLine("The number of odd numbers in this array is:" + sumOdd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably it's this line: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`. `System.in` doesn't exist in C#. Presumably you'll need to rewrite `Scanner` around using the static `Console` class instead.

Comment: can u pleas write the code

Comment: _"can u please write the code"_ - Wouldn't that defeat the point of you doing your homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is causing the error:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

`System.in` doesn't mean anything in C#, hence it is complaining because it is looking for a class named `in` in the `System` namespace.

In Java console application, `System.in` is typically the input buffer (keyboard).

In C#, to read a line from the `Console`, instead of `Scanner` (which doesn't exist), you can use `Console.ReadLine()`.  Of course it's not clear what is being read in your application (numbers?) so you may need to do some type conversion as `ReadLine()` returns a `string?`.

**Edit following OP request to read numbers from Console**

OP asked how to replace the existing Java code that reads numbers from the console with the C# equivalent.  Here is one *suggestion* (there are several approaches that accomplish the same):

```
int[] arr1 = new int[10];
Console.WriteLine("Before Selection Sort:");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    string text = Console.ReadLine();

    if (text != null && int.TryParse(text, out int value))
        arr1[i] = value;
    else
        Console.WriteLine("You must enter a valid number. Try again.");
}
```

Comment: @hananfarhat This is the correct answer to your question.  You asked why you are getting the error, this is why.

Comment: yes yes i didn't mean that  first of all thanks for helping

Comment: but i mean the correct typing i mean how to write it since i dont know c#

Comment: @hananfarhat What is your code trying to do?  Read 10 numbers from the console?

Comment: read 10 numbers from console then sorting them form small to big and then put how much even numbers are thier and how mush odd number are thier

Comment: @hananfarhat [Reading an integer from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24443827/9363973)

Comment: MindSwipe thanks for helping,but martin understands what i want and he is helping

Comment: @Martin you understand what I want right?

Comment: I've added an example that shows how to achieve this.  The link that was helpfully provided by @MindSwipe shows several other methods that achieve the same.

Comment: @hananfarhat Have you taken a look at the code I added?

Comment: Yes of course ,but i dont want to ask many questions and i am facing problems such as what to replace scan. next with

Comment: @hananfarhat You will see in the answer I have shown you have to use `Console.ReadLine()` to replace `scanner`.  SO policy is to ask single questions with single answers - if you have another question you should ask it separately

Comment: before 7 days i am not allowed to ask

Comment: @hananfarhat I'm sorry to hear that but I already answered the question you asked, and then answered the second question you asked.  You haven't even marked my answer as correct and are now asking further questions.  I can't help you further in this question

Comment: sorry i am new to stack