# In a console program, how do I create a form that a person could fill out?

Tags: c#, console

What I want to be able to do is create a display in the console that shows this:

---

Name:

Date:

Birthday:

---

And after data is entered next to each of the colons and enter is pressed, It activates a method of some sort that would set variables to the data. How do I do this?

Response to first few comments:

Well, the reason why i am using console is because i am trying to learn C# and i am trying to do this the same way I learned for C, by starting with the console. I thought this would be the easiest way to display the program for the user. From the comments above, it seems I need to learn something else.

Comment: You can't do that, in a console app. You can prompt for name, then date, then birthday - but you can't display all three prompts at once and have the user "fill them in".

Comment: I disagree with @Blorgbeard, you can. Set the cursor position, write out the prompts, then set the cursor position to the first one, read key-by-key until you get an enter/tab, then go to the next field and repeat. The question though is why use a console app when this is trivially easy in Winforms or any other windowing UI?

Comment: You would have to add quite a few things including a _message pump_ but by which time it's arguably no longer a console app.  So you may be better off doing a WinForms app in the first place

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` / `Console.ReadLine` - is this really hard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read user input from console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280591/read-user-input-from-console)

Comment: Well, the reason why i am using console is because i am trying to learn C# and i am trying to do this the same way I learned for C, by starting with the console. I thought this would be the easiest way to display the program for the user. From the comments above, it seems I need to learn something else.

Comment: For a console UI-like interactive 'form' use a library such as an ncurses-clone; or better, a library on top of such.

Comment: @T.S.: that question is already closed, just you to remind.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm wrong but this is my interpretation of your question:

```
Console.Write("Name: ");
var name=Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Date: ");
var a = Console.ReadLine();
var date = DateTime.Parse(a);
Console.Write("Birthday: ");
var b = Console.ReadLine();
var birthday = DateTime.Parse(b);
```

I know my code is badly-written, but it can do what you want, except line-by-line instead of "create a display" and type it in.

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for but i appreciate the effort.

Comment: @RahulShah: Maybe not exactly what you're looking for. But that's how user input is been read in console app.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.Write("Name: ");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Date: ");
string d = Console.ReadLine();
string date = DateTime.Parse(d);
Console.Write("Birthday: ");
string b = Console.ReadLine();
string birthday = DateTime.Parse(b);
```

Comment: This is the exact, line by line copy of @ProudNoob's answer.

Comment: @abatishchev: actually, it is not. I see plenty of differences.I don't know C# so cannot judge if those differences are significant, but this is *not* just a copy.