# Converting input of seconds to Days, Hours, Minutes using methods process in C#

Tags: c#, methods, time

I have checked a bunch of places with very minimal help to help me figure out a methods way in visual studios to open up the console when running the code to prompt the user from the Console.Writeline("Please enter seconds to convert: ");  to input the number of seconds that they are trying to convert, once thats put in it would then print the results of the conversion as "Your result is 00:00:00" . Im still in the process of learning more about c# so i have one slightly basic understanding so far and a basic solution but what i currently have is not that I'm trying to have for this project. My solution so far is :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(36100556);
        Console.WriteLine(t.Days);
        Console.WriteLine(t.Hours);
        Console.WriteLine(t.Minutes);
        Console.WriteLine(t.Seconds);
        Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do: `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")`?  You can use the built in `ToString` method to actually format a time directly.

Comment: cant you just use simple time math? `minutes = seconds / 60`, `hour = minutes / 60`, and so on?

Comment: It looks like you need to learn about [`Console.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`TimeSpan.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It seems title is misleading, real problem is to input values and then it's a duplicate of [Read user input from console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280591/read-user-input-from-console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number of seconds:");
double sec = 0;
// Check if user input correct integer
while(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out sec))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your data is invalid. Please input again:");
}
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec);
Console.WriteLine("Your result is " + t.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Just be aware that the timespan ToString overload only exists in .NET 4 and above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to follow these steps:

1) Send the message requesting the time with the Console.WriteLine.

2) Use the command Console.ReadLine, this will make the console to wait until the user puts the time that need to convert.

3) Read the value and make the math.

4) Display the value using WriteLine.

5) After display the value, put another Consol.ReadLine in order to avoid the console to hide before the user reads the result.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.Write("Enter Number of Seconds: ");
string SecondsStr = Console.ReadLine();

Double Seconds = 0;
if(!Double.TryParse(SecondsStr, out Seconds))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number entered");
}
else
{
    TimeSpan Time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Seconds);    
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Days: {0}, Hours: {1}, Minutes: {2}, Seconds: {3}", Time.Days, Time.Hours, Time.Minutes, Time.Seconds));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var x = Console.ReadLine()` to read input from the console. May have to do some conversions since it will read a string of characters. You can utilize something like `Convert.ToDateTime(x)` or something to convert to whatever data type you need.

Comment: He wants to input seconds and convert it to a TimeSpan.