# Why is this C# code outputting the wrong integer?

Tags: c#

So i am currnently trying to get into programming with C# with absolutely no expierience whatsoever. So i tried making a simple program that reads user input and outputs it again to the user. Now the name part is all fine, but when i try to input my age as for ex. 20 y/o, it always writes "Your input has been saved. You are 49 Year(s) old." Whatever number i put in, it always gives me 49, and i can't see any problem in the code that would cause this. Do you know what's wrong?

```
        Console.Write("Insert Age: ");
        int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
        if (age < 18)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Whoops! Looks like you are only " + age + " Year(s) old! You are too young to have your input saved.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your input has been saved. You are " + age + " Year(s) old.");
        }
```

Comment: Try Console.ReadLine instead of .Read. .Read reads a character, not a string, and when you convert a character to an int you get its code point value, at least for these characters. 0 is code point 48, 1 is 49, and so on.

Comment: `for ex. 20 y/o` It should be giving you `50` for an input of `20`. See www.asciitable.com

Comment: As a beginner, one of the first things you should learn is that conversions *look* simple but are the cause of **so** many issues. Any time you use `Convert`, or insert a cast, etc, you should make sure you have a rock solid understanding of why you're doing it. Far too many beginners throw conversions at code that won't compile (or just insert `.ToString()` everywhere, which is equivalent) without trying to understand.

Comment: [Difference between Console.Read() and Console.ReadLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825943/difference-between-console-read-and-console-readline)

Comment: Storing the result of `Console.Read()` into a variable before converting it would make the issue easier to see.  The variable would contain only a single character.

Comment: Any time you don't understand what a method is doing, the first thing you should do is [read its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Console_Read).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read user input from the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280591/how-can-i-read-user-input-from-the-console)

Answer (score 1):

**Console.Read()** method read just a single character from the console. If you want to read a number, 20 or 77 for example, you need **Console.ReadLine()** method. This will read for the entire line which will contain your number.

I strongly recommend you to use **int.TryParse()** method instead of **Convert.ToInt32()** method because in some cases the conversion will fail. For example if someone type the input in the wrong format and he will introduce this line: **20a**. Then your program will crash.

To use **int.TryParse()** method is very simple. Your code will looks like this:

```
    Console.Write("Insert Age: ");
    if( true == int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine()) )
    {
       if (age < 18)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Whoops! Looks like you are only " + age  
                          + " Year(s) old! You are too young to have your input saved.");
       }
       else
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Your input has been saved. You are " 
                             + age + " Year(s) old.");
       }
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("This is not a number."); // Or any message you want
    }
```

To make this code shorter you can try to write something like this:

```
    Console.Write("Insert Age: ");
    if( true == int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine()) )
    {
       Console.WriteLine( age < 18 ? 
         "Whoops! Looks like you are only " + age + 
         " Year(s) old! You are too young to have your input saved." :
         "Your input has been saved. You are " + age + " Year(s) old.");
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("This is not a number."); // Or any message you want
    }
```

And if you want to be even shorter then try:

```
    Console.Write("Insert Age: ");
    Console.WriteLine( int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine()) ?
       (age < 18 ?
            "Whoops! Looks like you are only " + age 
             + " Year(s) old! You are too young to have your input saved." 
         : "Your input has been saved. You are " + age + " Year(s) old.") 
      : "This is not a number.");
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Console.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) reads only the next character from standard input, 
and [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) reads the next line of characters from the standard input stream.

---

**Source** verbatim from [@VMAtm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213550/vmatm):
[Difference between Console.Read() and Console.ReadLine()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825943/difference-between-console-read-and-console-readline)

Answer (score 0):

the issue is a basic understanding problem. .NET does everything fine here.

Please have a look on the [Console.Read()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_Read) method. As you can see, it returns an `Int32` value. Meaning, in your case: it reads the first `char` of the input stream. If you enter "23" in the console, then the 2 is considered to be a `char`, which represents, according to [ASCII](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*DdgD00dAdXggzMdWDt7GSA.png), the value **50**. After that, you take this *50* and convert it to an Integer:  `age = 50`.

**Possible Solution**

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_ReadLine)

```
int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just to add clarification to this answer, **only** the `2` is used, because it only reads one character at a time. The `Read()` method already returns an integer so no conversion is necessary there. The `ReadLine()` method on the other hand returns a string, so the value needs to be converted to an integer.