# Guid.TryParse vs SqlGuid.Parse

Tags: sql, .net, guid

Using .Net framework 4, I have following input string

```
String s = "9330e655-63d4-4aee-be79-505554256bd3"
```

I want to write a function that will return true or false as to whether or not any input string is a valid SqlGuid:

**Method 1:**

```
' Parse to validate ...
ok = true
try
   s_uid = SqlGuid.Parse( s )
catch e as Exception
   ok = false
end try
return ok
```

However, the ASP.Net framework also provides the Guid.TryParse() method, ie:

**Method 2:**

```
' Parse to validate ...
ok = Guid.TryParse( s )
```

My question: Which is more efficient and what do most use to validate SQL GUIDs  (Method 1 or 2)?

Comment: Use `Guid.TryParse` , and don't use `try-catch` to validate if you have an option of `TryParse`.

Comment: Also see: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4946774/961113) from Eric Lippert

Comment: guid.tryparse does have a try-catch and does tons of other validation, if you want speed, maybe look at regex?

Comment: FYI, `Guid.TryParse` has nothing to do with ASP.NET. It's part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: scratch regex, just did a quick benchmark and it is not a fast option

Answer (score 1):

If you're *just checking validity* then you can use either method, and `Guid.TryParse` will allow you to validate without doing expensive exception handling.

Be aware, however, that the string representations of `Guid` and `SqlGuid` are not the same, so a string generated from a `Guid` should not be used to create a `SqlGuid` since it will result in a different GUID value.

Answer (score 1):

best practice would be to use the build-in TryParse but if you want to look at the speed/performance itself here some quick benchmark.

don't forget to build as Release and don't run it from visual studio.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(@"\b[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-F0-9]{12}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            string s = "9330e655-63d4-4aee-be79-505554256bd3";
            SqlGuid resultSql;
            Guid result;
            var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            bool valid;

            valid = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000; ++i)
            {
                try
                {
                    resultSql = SqlGuid.Parse(s);
                    valid &= true;
                }
                catch
                { 
                    valid = false;
                }
            }

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("sql try-catch {0}ms all valid {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, valid);

            sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            valid = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000; ++i)
            {
                try
                {
                    result = Guid.Parse(s);
                    valid &= true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("guid try-catch {0}ms all valid {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, valid);

            sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            valid = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000; ++i)
            {
                valid &= Guid.TryParse(s, out result);
            }

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("tryparse {0}ms all valid {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, valid);

            sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            valid = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000; ++i)
            {
                valid &= regex.IsMatch(s);
            }

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("regex {0}ms all valid {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, valid);


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```